# Using grep to filter

Tags: grep

Suppose I have a file.txt with the following lines :

```
hello myname1 is yellow.pcapng red
festive myname33 is hddd.pcapng dfdf
crude myname44 is hello.pcapng
```

Now my goal is to filter to the lines so it outputs to out.txt as follows :

```
myname1 yellow.pcapng
myname33 hddd.pcapng
myname44 hello.pcapng
```

Now I know that I can use :

```
grep -oh "\w*myname\w*" /tmp/file.txt  > /tmp/out.txt
grep -o '[^ ]\+g' /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/out.txt
```

to get the both respective parts of the expression individually.
How do I combine these commands so that I get my desired output?

Comment: do you have to use `grep`? You have a problem that's begging for an `awk` solution, and awk should be available everywhere that grep is.

Comment: I was only familiar with grep and not awk, could you show me how to do using awk possibly?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It's actually begging for a `cut` solution, since this is exactly what `cut` is supposed to do

Comment: Good thing there [is a cut solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522769/117549), @ChatterOne!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your sample data, you could assume that words #2 and #4 are what you want to extract; you'd express that in awk with:

```
awk '{ print $2, $4 }' < /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/out.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f2,4 < /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk instead of grep.

```
awk '{print $2,$4}' /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/out.txt
```

You are piping the output of `cat file.txt` to `awk`.

Then using awk expressions `'{print $2,$4}'`, you are printing the 2nd and 4th field of the split line, with a space to separate.

Your output will be how you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Could do this too:

`cat file.txt | sed "s/.*\(myname[0-9]*\) is \([^ ]*\).*/\1 \2/g" | grep ^myname > /tmp/out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Since shell script method has been provided  above, Tried in Python and worked fine too

```
#!/usr/bin/python
o=[]
k=open('i','r')
for z in k:
    o.append(z.strip().split(' ')[1])
        o.append(z.strip().split(' ')[3])
for d in range(0,len(o),2):
    print " ".join(o[d:d+2])
```

output

```
myname1 yellow.pcapng
myname33 hddd.pcapng
myname44 hello.pcapng
```